# Share variables among MATLAB unit tests

Tags: matlab, unit-testing

I am writing a unit test to make sure that some refactored MATLAB code produces the same results as the legacy code.  There are several tests, but running the legacy code involves time-consuming activities, namely loading multiple files and processing the data to produce a matrix `A`.  I would like to use setupOnce to run the legacy code and then pass `A` to the various unit tests.  Is that feasible?  If so, how?  My code might look something like this:

```
function setupOnce(testCase)
    expectedA = buildOldMatrix; % calls legacy code
end

function testNewMatrix(testCase)
    actualA = buildNewMatrix; % calls new code
    verifyEqual(testCase, expectedA, actualA)
end
```

Comment: I assume returning ```expectedA``` from ```setupOnce()``` as a output and then using it as an input parameter in ```testNewMatrix()``` isn't what you want. You could let ```setupOnce()``` save the old matrix as a .mat file, if you matrix isn't huge. Then ```testNewMatrix()``` would just need to load that file and do the comparision instead of running your time-consuming legacy code.

Comment: I suggest using `save` and `load`, as @Till says

Comment: @Till returning `expectedA` from `setupOnce()` as an output and then using it as an input parameter in `testNewMatrix()` sounds like a good solution, but I haven't been able to find the syntax to do it in a function-based test.

Comment: Adding an input to the test function, e.g. `function testNewMatrix(testCase,legacyResults)` results in a warning: `The "testNewMatrix" function must accept exactly one argument.`

Comment: Actually, I wasn't really aware that we're speaking about function-based testing^^ Passing arguments might be not possible, then you need to work with class-based tests, I think. Someone might correct me here, if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're after is storing the `expectedA` inside `testCase.TestData`, so that it can be used in subsequent test cases. Like this (this is all "myTests.m"):

```matlab
function tests = myTests
% Run using: runtests('myTests.m')
tests = functiontests(localfunctions);
end

% Build and store "A"
function setupOnce(testCase)
% Store a matrix for use in later tests
testCase.TestData.A = magic(3);
end

% A test case
function testOne(testCase)
expectedA = testCase.TestData.A;
actualA = magic(3);
verifyEqual(testCase, actualA, expectedA);
end

% Another test case
function testTwo(testCase)
expectedA = testCase.TestData.A;
actualA = magic(3).'; % Deliberately wrong
verifyEqual(testCase, actualA, expectedA);
end
```

There's more in the doc [here](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/write-test-using-setup-and-teardown-functions.html).

Comment: As always, Read The Full Manual.  I had looked at that doc page, but missed the TestData part.

Comment: I must admit it was new to me - I'm more familiar with class-based unit tests, but I felt sure there must be a way to do it with function-based tests.